# Handwriting inputting python

Tags: python, input

Is there any library/method which allows for the inputting of a signature, and converting that into an image (and possibly extrapolating the name from the signature)?

Comment: Too broad. Can you be a bit specific about your question. [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) for converting to image and image processing.